# Disable `Don't load tabs until selected` for a particular website

Tags: firefox

I use a lot of tabs, and in Firefox's configuration I have both:

`When Firefox starts: Show my windows and tabs from last time`

and

`Don't load tabs until selected`

**PROBLEM:** While I love this behavior, only one tab makes me sad: my Webmail tab, which shows "zero new email" until I remember and click on it so that it loads and starts fetching emails.

Is it possible to disable `Don't load tabs until selected` for a particular website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution that I personally use for such a scenario is to right-click -> `Pin Tab`. Pinned tabs override the `Don't load tabs until selected` function. I suppose the reason is because they are considered to have higher priority than other tabs.

Pinned tabs become highlighted in blue once there are new updates in that tab, such as when receiving a new email.

Here's a screenshot of pinning a tab:

[image: Demonstrating pinned tabs]

Here's another showing a pinned Gmail tab that is announcing the arrival of new email(s):

[image: Highlighted pinned tab. Works in realtime]

Comment: And, if you are using Gmail you can enable Labs in Settings and add "Unread message icon". This will put the unread message count into the gmail favicon.

Comment: Excellent first answer Ugo!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)